# How to get value of dropdown item (not select-option statement)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

If I ve dropdown of

```
<select id="city">
        <option value="blore">Bangalore</option>
        <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
        <option value="che">Chennai</option>
        <option value="jaipur">Jaipur</option>
        <option value="hyd">Hyderabad</option>
        <option value="mum">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="pune">Pune</option>
</select>
```

then the value of dropdown selected can be extracted using :

```
document.getElementById('city').value
```

But since we cant style the select-option dropdown, I was wondering is there any way where I define a list type dropdown and can extract the value user selects in javascript.

Something like.
(Dropdown using lists)

```
<ul id="city">
<li value="something1">Something1</li>
<li value="something2">Something2</li>
<li value="something3">Something3</li>
</ul>
```

and `document.getElementById('city').value`

Kindly correct me if m wrong or is there any other way to define a styled dropdown menu whose value can be extracted in javascript for processing.

If more code is required kindly put it in comment.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry, but your question is way too broad for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're basically looking to mimic the functionality of a form element without using one, it's going to take a little extra work in javascript. jQuery will greatly simplify this, so I'll use it for this example. Common practice these days when wanting to attach arbitrary data to an html element is to use an attribute prefixed with "data-". You'll see why in a second.

So, for your example, you could use the markup:

```
<ul id="city" data-value="">
<li data-value="something1">Something1</li>
<li data-value="something2">Something2</li>
<li data-value="something3">Something3</li>
</ul>
```

Style your list however you like, including js to create the "dropdown" effect, etc. I'd suggest looking into [bootstrap's dropdown component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) if you'd like to save more time.

Finally, you'll need to create the javascript to select a value, and put that value as the 'selected' one in your parent element:

```
$('#city li').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().data('value', $(this).data('value')); 
});
```

This is making use of jQuery's .data() method as a shortcut for setting and getting data- attributes.

You can now access the currently-selected value by calling:

```
$('#city').data('value');
```

Without jQuery, there is more involved. I'll leave it up to you whether you think it's useful to pursue a vanilla js solution.

Comment: It is much more complicated than this to create a dropdown that is actually useful and does not create more problems than it solves. OP should use a ready solution that is professionally built.

Comment: You mean like the bootstrap one I linked to? I mean, I'm all for using fleshed-out, battle-tested components as the next guy, but maybe OP just wanted to learn how it's done? I don't see anything wrong with a little thought exercise and tutoring.

Comment: OP is not even close to creating their own dropdown if lacking the knowledge you are teaching in your answer. You should not encourage the OP, they should learn the basics first.

Comment: They're not saying they're going to use this in the next global banking, ICBM Space Station controller. Why not give somebody the benefit of the doubt and allow people to experiment and learn? That's what programming is all about, and being exclusionary directly counters the entire purpose of this site. If their question is a duplicate, by all means treat it as such. But I can't fathom how dismissing somebody who's trying to learn basics is productive or courteous.

Comment: If OP wanted to learn then they would not have asked this question. OP is asking for teh codez. The purpose of the site is not to teach the basics to people who are unable to read the basic tutorials themselves, and has never been. You cannot really help here, because a good answer to this question would be a whole book (and even more, depending on the OP's current knowledge).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matt. I ll experiment around with it and modify according to my needs.

And Kapa, I did try searching for relevant links for similar problem and how to approach solving it but didn't get any hence posted the question. I even tried experimenting around with my code but no results. Still thanks for your comments. :)